# Cannot find GOOGLE appId for project : <projectid>

Tags: android, firebaseui

I'm implementing google authentication on firebase using the firebaseui lib.
Firebase is working properly, i can access the data in my database, and email/password auth is also working, although when i try to login using google i always get the same error :

```
W/AuthMethodPicker: Firebase sign in with credential unsuccessful
com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occured. [ Cannot find GOOGLE appId for project: 12345678. ]
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafg.zzes(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafd$zzg.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafo.zzet(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafo$zza.onFailure(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafj$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
```

i know that this value is extracted from the json file and added as a resource property during build by com.google.gms.google-services plugin, so i checked and the property was in fact added but for some reason it seems that firebase is not able to read it at runtime..

Any idea about what i can be doing wrong?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Before you generated your app's `google-services.json`, did you enable Google Sign In for your project?
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have a Firebase project
2. In that project make sure you have enabled GOOGLE AUTHENTICATION
3. Now Download a fresh copy of the google-services.json and replace it with the old one inside your app folder

Answer (score 0):

yes i enabled google auth before generating the json.
Another detail is descovered in the meantime if that google auth does work without firebase-ui. 
What i did was to try their example of google auth (adding to my app source)  and it worked without issues.

Adding firebase-ui seems to remove the need for some extra logic so i wanted to use it, but it seems i'm either missing something or there is a bug on firebase-ui .

Answer (score 0):

Leaving this here for anyone that might encounter this issue now.

Had a similar problem to above only difference is i had it on iOS. Would try to launch and sign in through google and would get the same internal error.

What worked for me was enabling the identity kit on google API and then checking "Google" and the other providers I used. You can find this on the google cloud console -> API Manager -> Dashboard.

App restart, clean build and then everything worked.